# holding onto events while mapping over an object

Tags: reactjs

Below I am looping over an object, that contains a bunch of questions. When the object is rendered, with the question and input tag the on change event handler breaks.  Thoughts?

```
    convertPropsIntoObject(){

    var obj = this.state.questionMap
    var data = _.map(obj, function(value, prop) {
        return (
             <div className="field" key={uuidv4()}>
                <label className="label">{prop}
                </label>
              <div className="control">
                  <textarea 
                      className="textarea" 
                      placeholder={'Enter your response here'}  
                      defaultValue={value}
                      onChange={e => this.handleChange}
                      />
              </div>
            </div>

            )

    });

    return (
        <form onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
            {data}
        <button className="button is-success is-outlined">Resubmit your responses</button>
        </form>

        )



}
```

This is my error

```
   TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleChange' of undefined
onChange
src/Components/CompletedSubmission/CompletedIceBreakerForm.js:40
  37 |            className="textarea" 
  38 |            placeholder={'Enter your response here'}  
  39 |            defaultValue={value}
> 40 |            onChange={e => this.handleChange()}
  41 |            />
  42 |    </div>
  43 | </div>
```

Comment: You missed `()` brackets `onChange={e => this.handleChange()}`

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleChange' of undefined
onChange
src/Components/CompletedSubmission/CompletedIceBreakerForm.js:40
  37 |            className="textarea" 
  38 |            placeholder={'Enter your response here'}  
  39 |         defaultValue={value}
> 40 |         onChange={e => this.handleChange()}
  41 |            />
  42 |    </div>
  43 | </div>

Comment: Use arrow function for `_.map` callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback to `_.map` is called from within a different execution context, so the `this` keyword will be referring to lodash.

Use an arrow function instead for implicit `this` binding:

```
var data = _.map(obj,(value, prop) => { ... });
```